# When I duplicate a print composer, item properties is blank

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to have several, identically placed and scaled, print composers.
One with a grid, and the others without. Each showing different layers.
I set up one, added layers, then used duplicate to replicate it on a new composer, but when I do this, the item properties is blank and I can't select the map. This means I can't remove the grid.
I also found that, although I could refresh the view on the first duplicate, I could not do so on subsequent duplicates.
Is this a bug?
How can I set up my print composers?
I'm exporting them to another program to edit and then overlay so they have to show the exact same area, at the same scale, just with different info within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO select the map, double click on the space. For some reason, single clicking doesn't work on the duplicated composer.